# Search through a markdown using sed

Tags: awk, sed

#### The Problem

I multiple Markdown files in a folder, formatted like so...

```
# Cool Project
* Random Text 
* Other information
TODO: This is a task
TODO: This is another task
```

And I've written a script that pulls out all the strings that start with TODO from all the files...

```sh
 ag TODO: ~/myfolder/journal | sed  's/\(^.*:\)\(.*\)/TODO:\2 /g' | sed ''/TODO:/s//`printf "\033[35mTODO:\033[0m"`/'' | sed ''s/![a-zA-Z0-9]*/$(printf "\033[31;1m&\033[0m")/''
```

and this gives me an output like this

```
TODO: This is a task
TODO: This is another task
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to look backward from the pattern using sed to identify and pickup the line that starts with `/^# /` and appended it to the end of the string... something like this

```
TODO: This is a task # Cool Project
TODO: This is another task # Cool Project
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed -n '/^#/h;/^TODO/{G;s/\n/ /p}' file
```

Search for lines beginning with # and add to hold space (h) Then when a line begins with "TODO", append hold space to pattern space (G) and substitute new lines for a space.

Answer (score 5):

You could do this in a single `awk` itself. With your shown samples, could you please try following, written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk '/^# /{val=$0;next} /^TODO/{print $0,val}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '             ##Starting awk program from here.
/^# /{            ##Checking condition if line starts from hash space then do following.
  val=$0          ##Creating val which has current line value getting stored init here.
  next            ##next will skip all statements from here.
}
/^TODO/{          ##Checking condition if line starts with TODO then do following.
  print $0,val    ##Printing current line and val here.
}
' Input_file      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```